# Interface for a nested parent-child structure

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an interface for a recursive parent-child structure. The structure looks like this

```
const data = [
    { id: 'a', children: [
        { id: 'b', children: [
           { id: 'c', children: [ .... ] }
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

Based on this, I can create the following interface

```
interface IData {
    id: string;
    children: IData[];
}
```

and this this fine (I think). But in my case `IData[]` should be more dynamic. `IData[]` should be the default type. So, I thought I could use generics, like this:

```
interface IData<X = IData[]> {
    id: string;
    children: X;
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
Type parameter 'X' has a circular default.
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

its look like good

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICSARJUnoDeo6p6YAJgFzoDOUckA5gNwlkoAWYANhXDAgB+GjjxIA2gF02IAL6hF4aPGRosAORj1c+ADwANdAF4suyVIB8RdqUo16jCK1vouvfoJoHZCkEpQAewh6dApxdCpMLR1xU0JyanQAciRkgBo3bj4BCBoJVzIiRJpkgCMMrI9c-MKi0gT7FJRK9xyvdAlSKXQ-erIpPoG-UCA)

```
interface IData {
    id: string;
    children?: IData[];
}


interface INestData<X = IData[]> {
    id: string;
    children: X;
}


const data :INestData= { id: 'a', children: [
        { id: 'b', children: [
           { id: 'c', children: [  ] }
        ]}
    ]}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! This indeed works, but I cannot believe that this is the only solution. To me this is more of a work around, like using `any`